# SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token <"}

Tags: php, json

I have using ajax. Here creating json in PHP

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        var data='page=1';
        $('#loader_tracker').show();
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getDetails.php",
        data:data,
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data) {
            $('#loader_tracker').hide();
        },
         error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
         console.log(errorThrown);
         console.log(textStatus);
         },
         complete: function(){
            $('#loader').hide();
        }

        });
        return false;

});
```

PHP COde

```
require_once('dbConnection.php');
$connection = new dbconnection();
$con = $connection->connectToDatabase();
header('Content-type: text/json'); 
die($response);

$vendorId = 2;
$name = "sample";
$latitude = 100;
$longitude = 200;

$device_details=array('devices' => array());

    for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++)
{

$details =array('id' => $vendorId, 'name' => $name, 'lat' => $latitude, 'lan' => $longitude);
array_push($device_details['devices'],$details);
}

echo json_encode($device_details);
```

It gives  SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token <"} Error

I cant find issue for this. I dont know how to add json format like this  one[{devices:[{...}]}]

Comment: getDetails.php in this file check that there is no HTML on the top

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line below (which makes your response be invalid json):

```
print_r ("$device_details");
```

Comment: I have add this line for testing.. Even i have remove this line, same error occur

Comment: I dont know where it is. i think its json format error

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code

```
print_r ("$device_details");
$response=json_encode($device_details);
print $response;
```

to,

```
echo json_encode($device_details);
die();
```

Comment: Now i get this error  SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token ["}

Comment: can you replace `array_push($device_details['devices'],$details);` to `$device_details['devices'][] = $details;`

Comment: can you show the response string ? Or the result when you directly visit that page getDetails ? I thinks its json formating error

Comment: I have modify my question. see above

Comment: try 

`$device_details=array();

for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++)
{
...
array_push($device_details,$details);

}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove to `debug` code line `print_r ("$device_details");` from PHP file, 
And use `echo` json response and `terminate` code.

```
header('Content-type: text/json'); 
die($response);
```

And also add `header` sometime create problem with content information so please add proper header information.

Comment: @Mohaideen, can you add ajax response in question??